# RxJS Observable sometimes not updating

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm having some issues I don't understand while trying to implement an Angular service with RxJS Observables.

The important bits of the service are as follows:

```
export class BreadcrumbsService{
  route: BreadcrumbsRoute[];

  …

  getRoute(): Observable<BreadcrumbsRoute[]> {
   return of(this.route);
  }


  pushRoute(newroute: BreadcrumbsRoute){
   this.route.push(newroute);
  }

  setRoute(newroute: BreadcrumbsRoute[]){
    this.route = [];
    for (const route of newroute) {
      this.route.push(route);
    }
  }

  …

}
```

---

The Component is subscribing to the GetRoute method as you'd expect:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getName().subscribe(name => this.servicename = name);
  this.service.getRoute().subscribe(newRoute => this.serviceRoute = newRoute);
}
```

---

I'm having several issues with this, which are both confusing and frustrating. In no particular order:

- Depending on what state the code is in, the subscriptions in `ngOnInit()` may sometimes fail.
- Rerunning the subscriptions (identical lines of code in a `poke()` method prompted by the user) will sometimes cause the subscriptions to behave as expected, and update linked UI elements.
- When the route subscription works, pushing route segments (manually, through the UI) with `pushRoute()` will cause the route UI to update correctly.
- Even when the route subscription works, pushing full route with `setRoute()` fails to update the UI. The underlying data does change as expected.

---

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

---

Edit: [Reproduced the issue on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yajjvk)

Steps to reproduce:

- Enter values into top two text boxes
- Click `Add to routes`
- Route display up to updates as expected

---

- Enter `/hello/world/` into either of the bottom two boxes
- Click `set new route`
- Observe that the route display does not update as expected
- Click `Poke`
- route display updates

Comment: I don't know how it could ever work. Could you make a stackblitz of the issue ?

Comment: I've added the Stackblitz as well as steps to reproduce

Comment: Instead of creating an observable with `of` in `getRoute`, you could use a Subject, as shown in [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). You would call `next()` to notify the observers when appropriate (e.g. in `pushRoute` and in `setRoute`).